# How do I target the first link inside a div with CSS?

Tags: css, pseudo-class, targeting

For example I have this:

```
<div>
  <a href="#">sample 1</a>
  <a href="#">sample 2</a>
  <a href="#">sample 3</a>
</div>
```

I want to target the first link with CSS.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can use the first-child selector:

```
div > a:first-child { /* your css */ }
```

Answer (score 10):

Try this code:

```
div > a:first-child{
   //your css code
}
```

Comment: I have an unordered list in the div as well and this CSS is targeting the first link in the unordered list as well. Is there any way to target JUST the first link in the div and not the first link in every div within the div?

Comment: you have to set an id tou your divfor example or a class and after you frite something like this: #divid a:first-child{} in this case you select the first link of the div with the id 'divid'

Comment: I understand but it's still selecting every first link inside the div of 'divid'

Comment: @DannyCooper I edited my answer. Now it will only target the first a inside the div, not the one in the list.

Comment: @DannyCooper understand, and edit my answer with what you want

Comment: @sticksu Bingo, I will award you the answer as soon as the site will let me.

Answer (score 3):

```
div a:nth-of-type(n)
{
   /* css */
}
```

where n is the number of line you want.. 
in your case

```
div a:nth-of-type(1)
{
   /* css */
}
```

Comment: `:first-child` is more concise and easier to read. It's also supported by more browsers.

Comment: what if someone wants the 2nd/3rd/4th... row?

Comment: nth isn't supported by some browser

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_nth-of-type.asp support all major excep ie8 and earlier